# How to stop audio playback in Firefox & use source.connect() hack

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, getusermedia

I'm developing a webapp that (in part) records some audio using recorder.js, and sends it to a server.  I'm trying to target Firefox, so I have to use this hack to keep the audio source from cutting off:

```
// Hack for a Firefox bug that stops input after a few seconds
window.source = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
source.connect(audio_context.destination);
```

I think that this is causing audio to be played back through the computer speakers, but I'm not sure.  I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to web audio.  My goal is to eliminate the audio that is being played out of the speakers.

EDIT:

Here's a link to my JS file on Github: https://github.com/miller9904/Jonathan/blob/master/js/main.js#L87

Answer (score 0):

you have to connect the source to the  node( through which you retrieve data which you are going to record), replace `this.node` with what variable name you have assigned to yuor node used for processing.

```
window.source.connect(this.node);
//this.node.connect(this.context.destination);
```

edit: just checked, connecting to destination is not compulsory, also make sure your node variable does not get garbage collected( which i am assuming is happening in your case, since recording stops after few seconds.)

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work.  I believe that the input cutting off is a documented bug in Firefox.  I added a link to my original post to my Github repo for this project.